# Need help comparing this series for a limit test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm not sure what to compare the following series to. Would $\dfrac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ work?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2-1}{n^4+2n+1}$$

Comment: Try limit comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: $\frac{n^2-1}{n^4+2n+1}\le \frac{n^2-1}{n^4}=\frac 1{n^2}-\frac1{n^4}$. follows from comparison test.

Comment: You need to show some of your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to prove that the series converges. For $n\geq 1$ we have:
$$n^4+2n+1>n^4-1=(n^2-1)(n^2+1)$$ Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \left|\frac{n^2-1}{n^4+2n+1}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{n^2-1}{n^4+2n+1}<\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{n^2-1}{(n^2-1)(n^2+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$
Now we see that the last sequence converges as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: Ah I forgot I can factor too, thanks! Also is there a chance there can be another series I can compare to my original series?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\frac{n^2-1}{n^4+2n+1} < \frac{n^2}{n^4+2n+1} <  \frac{n^2}{n^4} = \frac{1}{n^2}.$$